# Display Google Calendar UI

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

Could someone tell me how to display Google calendar UI using Google Calendar API V3 in Java? And even add some event in it.

Thank you.

Comment: Java is a very broad description. Java what? Servlet? JSP? Struts? Spring? Wicket?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is a full guide on the Developer Site that covers Java among other languages. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/firstapp

Comment: Hi Jonathanben, thanks for the link, I figured out how to use the google calendar api.